# Ordering by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see - row with id 6 is a response to row with id 3. I'd like to order my results set so that it would appear between rows 3 and 7. How to accomplish that? Doing: 
`select * from comments_comment order by updated_at, response_to_id` gets me exactly what you can see on the image.

Comment: ORDER BY id_integer ?

Comment: In this particular case it would work, but if someone would add a comment in response to no.3 but after comment no.7 was created then it wouldn't.

Comment: Isn't it the case? 6 is a response to id 3 and it was created after id 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(response_to_id, id), id
```

The logic behind your ordering is that you want parent records, and their children, to appear grouped together, with the parent appearing on top of the group.

The above `ORDER BY` is that is it identifies the group id by taking the `response_to_id` in the case of children, or the actual `id` in the case of a parent where the `response_to_id` is null.  Then within each group it orders by the `id` value.